# Selecting range of rows based on whether they contain certain value for a specific number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas dataframe` where one of the column contain just 2 different values (around 20,000 rows): 0 and 100. They occur in continuous series. For example, if there is a 0, there will be at least 50 more zeroes after that, before changing to 100.

I want to create a new column where it will output a 1 if the range of 0's in the above mentioned column is above a certain threshold (lets say 100). So if there are 100 0's continously occuring in the column, it will output a 1, else it will output a 0. How do I go about doing that? I tried `pandas.rolling` but that didn't work

Sample:

```
Input    Output
 0         1
 0         1
 0         1
 0         1
 0         1
```

In the above table, if there are 100 **continuous** 0, the output will be 1.

Comment: Could you provide sample input and output dataframes?

Comment: @J...S just added an example table

Comment: You just want to produce a `1` if the column value is above a threshold? And if there are 50  zeros you want 50 corresponding ones?

Comment: I want to output a 1 if and only if there are 100 continuous 0. Anything less than 100, I want to output a 0. And yes if there are 100 continuous 0, I want a 1 in every output column